# Roblox API Creating VIP Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, roblox

I'm trying to send a post request to url below to create vip servers externally. Even though i send X-CSRF-TOKEN and Cookie in .ROBLOSECURITY still getting Unauthorized.

```
const axios = require("axios");
require("dotenv").config();

const config = {
  method: "post",
  url: "https://games.roblox.com/v1/games/vip-servers/2567785013",
  headers: {
    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": process.env.TOKEN,
    Cookie: process.env.COOKIE,
    "Content-Type": "text/plain",
  },
  data: {
    name: "My Vip Server",
    expectedPrice: 10,
  },
};

axios(config)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error.response.statusText);
  });
```

Comment: Are you sure `process.env.TOKEN` and `process.env.COOKIE` have the correct values?

Comment: Yes i checked and they are correct